# Node.js 17.0.1 Gatsby error - "digital envelope routines::unsupported ... ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED"

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I am building a [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) site. I upgraded Node.js to **v17.0.1**, and when I run a build, there is an error:

```
Error: digital envelope routines::unsupported

opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

If I downgrade it to v16, it works fine, and the build will be successful. How can I fix this?

From googling, this may be a similar issue:
*[Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt #48](https://github.com/handshake-org/hs-airdrop/issues/48)*

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with webpack.

- If you are on version 4, this was **fixed in version 4.47.0** ([release](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.47.0)).
- If you are on version 5, this was **fixed in version 5.61.0** ([release](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.61.0)).

Upgrading webpack to a version beyond what is listed above should address the problem.

See this issue for further discussion when the bug was originally noticed:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532

Ultimately this was related to webpack using `md4` hashes and [their fix](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/14584) was to switch to using a WASM implementation of the `md4` algorithm rather than node's builtin (of which node's relies on OpenSSL, hence the error).

Note that while a member of the webpack team [had stated](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-960595837) they did not plan to backport the fix to webpack 4, version [v4.47.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.47.0) nonetheless included a custom `md4` implementation to [bring support for Node 18 and above](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/17628).

---

##### *Original Response:*

Gatsby / the tooling used in Gatsby must be using a [cryptographic algorithm or key size](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html) which is no longer allowed by default with OpenSSL 3.0.

From [Node.js 17's announcement post](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-js-17-is-here-8dba1e14e382#5f07):

> If you hit an `ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED` error in your application with Node.js 17, it’s likely that your application or a module you’re using is attempting to use an algorithm or key size which is no longer allowed by default with OpenSSL 3.0. A new [command-line option](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--openssl-legacy-provider), `--openssl-legacy-provider`, has been added to revert to the legacy provider as a temporary workaround for these tightened restrictions.

Running this on the terminal might look like:

```
node --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build
```

You can also pass this in via the [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions) environment variable.

So if you'd like to continue using the NPM script, you can change the `build` script to:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider gatsby build"
  }
}
```

Comment: This command does get rid of the error:
node --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build

Thanks a lot! 
Does it mean that it is down to Gatsby team (or even any modules it depends) to fix the issue in future?

Comment: Yes, from the error you posted, I can't be sure if it is gatsby directly or a module they are consuming. I imagine they'll have a bugfix release for this in the near future.

Comment: I upgraded webpack from 5.35.1 to 5.61.0 and it resolved my problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 304):

This might help. Add these scripts in the *package.json* file.

##### React:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

If you are on `Windows` and you are using `React.js` you can use `set` instead of `export` in your scripts as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "set SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "set SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

or

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
}
```

##### Vue.js:

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

If you are on `Windows` and you are using `Vue.js` you can use `set` instead of `export` in your scripts as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

or

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service --openssl-legacy-provider serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service --openssl-legacy-provider lint"
},
```

##### Angular:

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider  && gulp buildDev && ng serve ",
 "publish": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider  && gulp build && ng build --prod",
},
```

Comment: How to start development serve after these changes in vue?

Comment: The same as before: `npm run serve`

Comment: He, thanks alot for this. i have a simple question, what really causes this problem.

Comment: just run this command, inside the project root.

export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Comment: This worked, but I still do not understand the what the issue was. What caused this?

Comment: I'm using yarn and my package.json contains this command: "build-dev": "yarn install && webpack --config ./Config/webpack.config.dev.js --colors", How can I apply the fix here? Everything I tried did not work

Answer (score 207):

Quick fix: Run this in a terminal inside your React project.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: worked here with node v17 for Mastodon server. Thx!

Comment: Where does that go? In a script file? Manually in a terminal? When should it be applied? In what context? What should be run afterwards in that terminal? What do you mean by *"Run this in a terminal inside your React project"*? In what environment? In a [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) context? Something else? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70116509/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen 
Run this in a terminal inside your React project.
eg: 
```cd book_react_app```
```export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider```

@PeterMortensen Can you suggest an edit if this is not clear? Thank you

Comment: node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Comment: What did I write about not here in comments?

Comment: worked for me for an lwc/express server.

Comment: work for me on react native project. Using Node.js v18.13.0

Comment: Oh man, thank you! I've been dealing with this for hours! Again, Thank you!

Comment: No idea what it did but it worked. Can someone please explain? I don't see anything in source control so not quite sure what happened here

Answer (score 32):

This issue comes with the new update of Node.js 17.
In [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) you can change the script attribute in the *package.json* file to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make this work with older and newer versions of node? if you run this with an older version of node, then it throws an error saying the command line flag is not recognized

Answer (score 21):

I also had the same problem, so I just degraded the Node.js version:

- Uninstall Node.js
- Then download and install 16.13.0.

Comment: you can also utilize nvm to switch among node versions

Comment: I strongly recommend using nvm in every platform because you will have to switch from one to another for some reasons... Managing it manually is much easier than uninstalling etc...

Answer (score 12):

I think there are two solutions for this error we encountered after the new Node.js update.

1. Downgrade Node.js
2. *node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js* - you should add this code inside the .js file you find here:

   ```js
       const crypto = require("crypto");
       const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
       crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
   ```

Comment: none of the downgrade/export fixes worked! but this worked for me. i think ill use this fix temporarily until I reinstall my OS (it happened after I upgraded to fedora 36).

Comment: 2nd solution worked for me, 1st would've also worked, just don't this downgrading is a good idea.

Comment: This 2nd solution worked for me as well, setting the `hash` option in Webpack wasn't sufficient, maybe due to scss using the function as well?

Answer (score 6):

Use it as a build command for Vue.js 3 and Node.js v17.0.1:

```
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' vue-cli-service build"
```

Comment: Why the double quote? (At the end.)

Answer (score 5):

[Rajiv's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-js-17-0-1-gatsby-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-err-os/69746387#69746387) seems right as a workaround, but the syntax didn't worked for me in [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js). What worked was without the keyword "SET":

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

I have uninstalled my Node.js version 17.0.1 through the control panel.

Then I downloaded the Node.js version 16.13.1 from the nodejs.org and installed it, and then React Native starts and builds fine.

Comment: Re *"control panel"*: On Windows?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this similar issue in version 17.3.0.

1. I have uninstalled Node.js and installed version 16.13.0 and restarted.
2. By running in the new terminal, it got fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30745970)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with an Angular application on server -

1. I just downgraded the Node.js version locally to 14
2. The [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) image replaced with version [14.18.1](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/3101ce6b5b3a0308b58d464eef141e0043c3bf5b/14/stretch/Dockerfile). Earlier it was [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux)

You can find more details in Node.js' latest release documentation.

Comment: opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
how to fix this on yarn project

Answer (score 0):

While patching with `--openssl-legacy-provider` is more of a hack and a real solution would be to fix OpenSSL key size usage in Vue.js, React, etc.; a temporal workaround may be using an older version of Node.js indeed.

But I'd suggest not to downgrade Node.js; rather install NVM ([main](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)/win: [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)/[nodist](https://github.com/nullivex/nodist)/[nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs), the last one being cross-platform) and switch between versions on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should downgrade your Node.js or use nvm to switch between Node.js versions. I did this and React worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).