# ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED while attempting npx idk deploy of React app

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, aws-cdk

I am posting this to hopefully spare someone else some of the bang-head-on-desk moments I encountered.

I received the following error when attempting to run npx cdk deploy today:

```
npx cdk deploy
```

```
[12:19:19] Bundling asset ApplicationStack/WebApp/WebAppDeploy/WebAppDeploy/Asset1/Stage...
yarn run v1.22.15
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/.cache/yarn"
  because it is not writable. warning Selected the next
  writable cache folder in the list,
  will be "/tmp/.yarn-cache-501".
```

```
$ react-scripts build
```

```
warning Cannot find a suitable global folder.
Tried these: "/usr/local, /.yarn"
Creating an optimized production build...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
     at module.exports (/asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
     at handleParseError (/asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
     at /asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
     at /asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
     at /asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
     at iterateNormalLoaders (/asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
     at iterateNormalLoaders (/asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
     at /asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
     at runSyncOrAsync (/asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
     at iterateNormalLoaders (/asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
     at Array.<anonymous> (/asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
     at Storage.finished (/asset-input/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
     at /asset-input/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9 

asset-input/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:19 throw err;
^ Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
     at module.exports (/asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
     at /asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
     at /asset-input/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
     at /asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
     at /asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
     at context.callback (/asset-input/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
     at /asset-input/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103

{
     opensslErrorStack: [
         'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error'
     ],
     library: 'digital envelope routines',
     reason: 'unsupported',
     code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1 error

Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Failed to bundle asset ApplicationStack/WebApp/WebAppDeploy/WebAppDeploy/Asset1/Stage, bundle output is located
     at /Users/[my user]/PycharmProjects/ps-serverless-app/infrastructure/cdk.out/asset.8c7ae86f7dabf723a79310f22f328c471bdaec37da5325cd834784dc03a40eff-error:
Error: docker exited with status 1
Subprocess exited with error 1 FAIL
```

This error is a bit confusing as my version of node is `v16.13.0`
It appears that simply upgrading npm to `v8.1.3` is enough to trigger this issue.

It seems to be related to attempted use of MD4 algorithm.

I found an article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-17-0-1-causes-some-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported) that has a working solution for my specific situation. The answer by @Chesiremoe worked perfectly for me.

Unfortunately I do not have enough "street cred" on here to comment on that post and thank this user specifically but this answer was much appreciated!!

Adding this code to `node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js` resolved this issue:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack build failing with ERR\_OSSL\_EVP\_UNSUPPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider