# I keep getting Localhost:300 Connection Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to setup for react but my localhost:3000 is giving connection error after npm-start. Can anyone please help me how I can fix the error?
Please have a look at this screenshot to see the error

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node 17.0.1 causes some error - digital envelope routines::unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-17-0-1-causes-some-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution, you can fix this by using the legacy provider for `OpenSSL`. So, you need to edit the `package.json` and change the configuration of **start** and **build** in this way:

```
{
   ...

   "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
        "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
        ...

   },
   ...

}
```

Save the `package.json` file and execute the command *npm start* again and your application should start and open the browser with URL `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: I tried that, but it isn't working