# plaid squckstart/frontend will not start node.js error

Tags: node.js

opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Any ideas? May have something to do with open ssl token size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you cd into the project root and run `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` or put it in your package.json under your build command as such:

```
"build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider react-scripts build",
```

this should fix your issue. Let me know - good luck.

Also - check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-js-17-0-1-gatsby-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-err-os) regarding this or similar issue.