# opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],

Tags: reactjs

i imported a reat project on visual studio code. i installed npm and then i runned npm start . but it gives me error.  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],

can some ome help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be webpack related issue. You can either downgrade node to 16.13 or upgrade to webpack 5 to solve it. Running none with the option `--openssl-legacy-provider` should also work.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69665222/302793) for more detailed instructions for how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS & Linux:
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

For Windows:
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).