# Trying to build vue frontend for production. Keep getting code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'? What's this mean?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, frontend

I want to edit frontend, but when I try to build my edits I get this error:

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],  
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

I'm using Node.js v19.3.0. This shows with both 'npm run build' and 'npm run serve'...wasn't happening before today. No clue what it means. I've tried searching around online but everything pertains to React.

Comment: Here is same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-js-17-0-1-gatsby-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-err-os

Comment: Please make a search before posting.