# opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error'] in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, web-frontend

[I got this mistakes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKEIk.png)

I tried add router for my vue project. After i add something to my vue project. and I saw this mistakes. I changed my main.js file. So i saw this at my cmd:    at

> C:\Users\Ahmet\Vues\is-takip-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
> node:internal/crypto/hash:69   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm,
> xofLen); and I updated browserlist version PS
> C:\Users\Ahmet\Vues\is-takip-app> npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Need to install the following packages:

> browserslist@4.21.10 Ok to proceed? (y) Y Latest version:
> 1.0.30001519 Installed version:  1.0.30001204 Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file Installing new caniuse-lite version

Comment: Old versions of webpack use obsolete hashes that are disabled in recent versions of OpenSSL and (thus) nodejs -- DUPE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/ (which you could have found by searching for your error message!)